# Large Hadron Collider 2015 upgrade, what may we discover?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

I realise that the initial answer to my question that may come to mind is, "we don't know yet, obviously" But my question is hopefully not opinion based.

For example, does this upgrade have a probability  that evidence for supersymmetery will be found (or not) at this new energy level?

EDIT: since first posting this 3 months ago, I came across the excerpt below dated 27th July 2015 and posted at [CERN Update](http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2015/07/lhc-experiments-present-latest-results-vienna) and I wonder if the reference to confirming the Standard Model, at whatever  new energy level is involved,  is the usual procedure in testing any new accelerator?

> This has allowed the LHC collaborations to measure a full suite of detector performance parameters that demonstrate the readiness of the experiments for discovery physics and precision measurements. The next step was to confirm the Standard Model at the new energy of 13 TeV. After only a few weeks of data taking, the experiments have now “rediscovered” all of the known fundamental particles, apart from the so-called Higgs boson, for which more data are still required. The collaborations are thus ready to test the Standard Model at 13 TeV and the hope is to find evidence of new physics beyond this well-established theory. END EDIT

Comment: have a look here  "glipmsed particles that LHC may confirm" http://motls.blogspot.gr/2015/06/glimpsed-particles-that-lhc-may-confirm.html

Comment: Thanks Anna,  looks like a lot of confirmatory work if the "glimpses" part of the blog is anything to go by.

Comment: [What wasn't discovered by the SSC](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-supercollider-that-never-was/).